# Dynamic permissions setting for forms

Tags: workflow, infopath, permissions

I am currently using Sharepoint 2010 with forms designed by InfoPath. I have workflows setup such as when a form is created and checked in, the user has to select the workflow and submit it for approval.

Would it be possible to restrict the permission settings so that once the document is submitted for approval, that only the person and the approver can read it?

And only the approver can modify it, the submitter will only have read-only privileges?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something like this myself right now. There are a few things you can do here:

1. Depending on your requirements, if you have an Approvers permission group set up then you can make the list read-only for everyone but that group.
2. Make a view that filters on the approver/submitter so that it only shows their form in the view (although this won't achieve you true security)
3. Create views based on your security requirements and restrict them to certain groups, see here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433486/How-to-set-view-level-permissions-out-of-the-box-i
4. Setup section/field permissions inside the InfoPath form itself, see here: http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/infopath-user-roles-in-browser-enabled-forms-using-groups/

Answer (score 0):

you should create another workflow that changes permissions accordingly.
sharepoint designer has an action that does that. I had to do it in my case because our requirements were the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a basic approval workflow.

Enable content approval and set draft item security in list settings.